# Java 8: Getting a property from a List of a List

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, stream, java-stream

I am new in Java 8, and I want to get the first Phone that is not null from a list of contacts form a list of persons, but I am getting a incompatible types 
error

```
return segadors
                .stream()
                .map(c -> c.getSegadorMedium().stream().map(cm -> Objects.nonNull(cm.getPhoneSegador())))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Can you please share your phone class and the initialization of your list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  return segadors
            .stream()
            .flatMap(c -> c.getSegadorMedium().stream().filter(cm -> Objects.nonNull(cm.getPhoneSegador())))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
```

You need a `filter` in that `Objects.nonNull` check; plus since you are returning a `Stream`, you need a `flatMap` just before that